# How to make the character move in 8 directions without сam behind his back in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine, game-development

I'm new to Unity and I don’t know how to make the character move in 8 directions (without a script on the camera behind him) by installing the camera in a certain place, for example, like in the old resident evil 2 (not a remake).The script that I used before does not work correctly and does not interact with RigidBody objects. I spent about 2 days solving this problems and all to no avail ;(

Comment: Would this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4HpC--2iowE&t) help?

Comment: I tried and still the character does not interact with rigidbody objects.

Comment: does the player object have a collider? Do the other objects have colliders? Without more information / code I can't really help. That tutorial should work though, skipping around I can see that the player in it is colliding with other objects. Else, there are many other tutorials / guides for creating third person movement.

Comment: You could define 8 vectors in the x z plane to define your movement direction and either add force for rigidbody or better transform position with time.deltaTime and one of the 8 direction vectors